# Unable to bind my Button to create a new tab dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am new to c# and wpf. 
Im my project I am trying to create a new tabs/ remove tab dynamically using button click.
But I am not successfull.
Kindly suggest where I am wrong.

I have taken help from here
https://www.technical-recipes.com/2017/adding-tab-items-dynamically-in-wpf/
I did DataBinding using command for Add/Remove of tab.

I have other .cs files similar as mentioned above. Hence not copy-pasting them here.

Below is my code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="UI_1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UI_1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="758">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="20.8"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="118.4"/>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="118.4" Height="228"/>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="13*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,-0.4,118.2" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="Open Log File" />
                <MenuItem Header="Open Workspace" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Save as Workspace" />
                <MenuItem Header="Set Path host file" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Control">
                <MenuItem Header="Open Command Line View" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,0.2,-0.4,0.2" >
            <WrapPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                </Style>
            </WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid Width="180">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                        </Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Connect To" Margin="3,6,2.8,6" />
                    <TextBlock  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Log Cmd" Margin="3,8,2.8,8" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="IP/HostName" Margin="32,3,3.2,3"/>
                    <ComboBox
                    x:Name="Job" Grid.Row = "1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="32,3,42.2,6">
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Trace"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="List"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Dump"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Off"/>
                        <ComboBoxItem Content="On"/>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row = "1" Text="Line" Margin="6.4,3,2.2,6"/>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="27*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="45*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="46*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <GridSplitter Width="2"></GridSplitter>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
                <Grid  Grid.Column="1"  Width="120">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <Button Content="Play" Margin="2,5,2.2,2"  
                            Command="{Binding x.AddItem}"/>
                    <Button Content="Stop" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,5,2.2,2" 
                            Command="{Binding x.RemoveTab}"/>
                    <Button Content="Send" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="456" Grid.Row="3" >
                <TabControl x:Name="tabControl1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinHeight="50" Margin="0,0.2" Width="736"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Titles, Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </TabControl>
            </Border>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>


MainWindow.XAML.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace UI_1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public class Item
        {
            public string Header { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Titles
        {
            get { return _titles; }
            set
            {
                _titles = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Titles");
            }
        }

        static int tabs = 1;
        private ObservableCollection<Item> _titles;
        private ICommand _addTab;
        private ICommand _removeTab;

        public ICommand AddTab
        {
            get
            {
                return _addTab ?? (_addTab = new TabRelayCommand(
                    x =>
                    {
                        AddTabItem();
                    }));
            }
        }
        public ICommand RemoveTab
        {
            get
            {
                return _removeTab ?? (_removeTab = new TabRelayCommand(
                    x =>
                    {
                        RemoveTabItem();
                    }));
            }
        }
        private void RemoveTabItem()
        {
            Titles.Remove(Titles.Last());
            tabs--;
        }

        private void AddTabItem()
        {
            var header = "Tab " + tabs;
            var content = "Content " + tabs;
            var item = new Item { Header = header, Content = content };
            Titles.Add(item);
            tabs++;
            OnPropertyChanged("Titles");
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindowVM x;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            x = new MainWindowVM();
            this.DataContext = x;           
        }
    }
```

After clicking my Play button no new tab is adding

Comment: Do you ever assign an instance of MainWindowVM to the DataContext of your MainWindow?

Comment: @Clemens I did now, but still no result. Also in debug mode,hitting Play button doesnt hit my breakpoint set AddTab. I will also edit my code above whatever I just said

Comment: `Command="{Binding x.AddItem}"/>` uses an invalid property path. It should be `Command="{Binding AddItem}"/>`. You should have seen a data binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Clemens Ya thanks a lot. I can finally create new tabs and delete them